# Getting "'tuple' object has no attribute 'perimetre'?"

Tags: python, attributes, tuples, attributeerror

How to resolve the problem?
I try:

```
class plot():
    def __init__(self,length,width):
    self.length = length
    self.width = width
    
    def area(self):
    print("area is ",self.length*self.width)
    
    def perimetre(self):
    per = 2(self.length+self.width)
    print("perimeter is ",per)
a1 , p1 = plot(10,20),(10,20)

a1.area()
p1.perimetre()
```

and got this error:

```
<>:10: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma? 
<>:10: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma? <ipython-input-83-8515c6a74849>:10: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
   per = 2(self.length + self.width)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError
 Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-83-8515c6a74849> in <module>
      13 
      14 a1.area()
 ---> 15 p1.perimetre()
 
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'perimetre'
```

Comment: Format the code properly. Use proper code format to include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Change `a1, p1 = plot(10,20),(10,20)` to `a1, p1 = plot(10,20), plot(10,20)`. You are instantiating a `plot` for `a1` but then you instantiate a tuple for `p1` by only using parentheses.

Also this code here `per = 2(self.length+self.width)` is not valid. You're trying to call `2` like its a function.